# React + Redux connecting error. Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare, WrappedComponent})

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here is a sendBox https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-euler-7mpi7?file=/src/main.js

as you can see it gives me error. What I'm trying to do is connecting Redux store in main.js. If you delete `connect` in main.js and leave component as is it will be working. But once you use `connect` in main.js it breaks the React app. What am I doing wrong while connecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your object in routes.js

```
{
    url: "/",
    component: Main,
    exact: true
}
```

Here, the Main doesn't represent a component favorable to be passed to Route Element.
(possibly after wrapping to connect the return structure is different)

Try changing that to

```
{
    url: "/",
    component: <Main/>,
    exact: true
}
```

and it would work.